# how to control fine details from overhanging part to not build upwards

Tags: print-quality, support-structures

I noticed that when printing small teeth on a pulley that the angle is not matching the design angle. I am printing without any support structure.

Overview:

[image: overview]

Detail:

[image: Detail in question]

Printed:

[image]

The printed overhang incline angle under the tooth looks good (maybe not quite steep enough;) but the top angle of the reclining section looks too flat. It is as if the tooth is too perky.

(I have observed a similar behavior when printing overhanging corners. They build upward more quickly.)

What is causing this, and how to prevent it?

I reduced the speed for the outer layer to 30 mm/s, the infill is set to 40 mm/s. Layer (Z) is set to 0.1 mm. Material PLA 1.75 mm, nozzle 0.4 mm.

Cura layer detail:

[image: Cura detail]

Cura Prepare

[image: Cura prepare]

Cura Preview

[image: close up]

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is unsupported overhangs. There is not enough material to support the first layer of each small tooth. Have a look at how your slicer slices the first couple layers at the bottom. It might be that it tries to reduce the angle to 45°, so that it can print overhangs, or the overhangs are drooping before the next layer can assist with support.

Looking at your first two images, I think the printed top part of the tooth is actually quite similar to your 3D design.

You can fix this by making the tooth profile from the side have a 45° slope to maximum height, and the same on the top if you want the teeth to appear symmetrical.

[image]

Comment: I would like to have it symmetrical, and was considering adjusting my design to be asymmetrical so it would print more symmetrically. I added two side view (last 2 images) of Cura's Prepare and Cura's Preview. It looks like Cura accepted my angle just barely.